# Cast a column to a decimal and specify its scale and precision without an arithmetic overflow error?

Tags: sql-server

I have a homework assignment and it asks

> Task: Write a select statement based on the InvoiceTotal column of the Invoices table:
>
> - Use the CAST function to return the first column as an integer value. Name it IntTotal.
> - Use the CAST function to return the second column as datatype decimal with one digit to the right. Name it DecimalTotal.
> - Use the CONVERT function to return the third column as a datatype that outputs 2 digits to the right of the decimal point and all comma’s to the left (i.e. 3, 106.34). Name it FormatTotal.

Here are my questions:

1. How do you write a select statement based on a column?
2. I've tried using `CAST(InvoiceTotal AS decimal(1,1)) 
   DecimalTotal` to specify its scale and precision as asked of me. I'm not sure if the syntax is correct but I'm getting an error that says:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 16
>
> Arithmetic overflow error converting money to data type numeric.`

Here's my code below

```
SELECT InvoiceTotal,
    CAST(InvoiceTotal AS int) intTotal,
    CAST(InvoiceTotal AS decimal(1,1)) DecimalTotal
FROM Invoices;
```

Comment: The error you have here is quite clear, the number you are trying `CONVERT` to a `decimal(1,1)` is too large. A `decimal(1,1)` can store 10 different values: `0.0`,`0.1`,`0.2`,`0.3`,`0.4`,`0.5`,`0.6`,`0.7`,`0.8`, and `0.9`; I'm guessing that the value of `InvoiceTotal` is none of those values.

Comment: I see. All the InvoiceTotal values have two decimals to the right (e.g. '125.28') So how do I 'Use the CAST function to return the second column as datatype decimal with one digit to the right'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decimal(1,1)` is a number that contains 1 digit, in total. Of those total digits, 1 of them is to the right of the decimal separator.

The first parameter is the total number of digits, not the number of digits to the left of the decimal separator. So if any of your numbers are 1 or larger, you need to increase the first parameter. E.g. `decimal(6,1)` gives you 6 total digits, with 1 to the right of the decimal. Which means you can have up to 5 digits to the left of the decimal.

Comment: What if the number to the left of the decimal ranges? The invoice totals range from 34.00 to 2314.47 and they all have two digits after the decimal. I'm just trying to make it one digit

Comment: @lolz - you don't have to fill all of the digits that are available. `decimal(6,1)` gives you *up to* 6 digits.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help. For the other question I had. Do you know how I write a select statement based on a column?

Comment: @lolz your `select` statement **is** based on a column, you are selecting a column, specifically `InvoiceTotal` as asked.